# JS slideshow - auto-play interrupting manual turn

Tags: javascript, slideshow, interrupt, manual

i just made a simple slideshow which changes images automatically and also has manual option so you can go forward and backward with images when you want.

Here is the problem: Auto function which changes the images is set to every 3 seconds. But if you for example click to change the slide after 2.5 seconds,the slide will change, but after 0.5 seconds auto function will also change to the next slide.

So i other way,auto function is interrupting manual change, **is there any way to reset autofunction after the slideshow is changed manually?**

here is the html code:

```
            <!doctype html>
            <html lang="en-US">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Chapter 11 - HTML Forms and JavaScript</title>

            </head>
            <body onload="autoRun()">

            <img src="slika1.jpg" id="slideshow" width="700px", 
             height="350px">
            <br/>
            <p id="caption">slika1</p>

            <a href="#" id="buttonNext">Next Slide</a><br/>
            <a href="#" id="buttonPrevious">Previous Slide</a>

            <script src="slideshow.js"></script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

JS code:

```
             document.getElementById('buttonNext').onclick=function(){
             changeImage(1); 
             return false; 
            }

             document.getElementById('buttonPrevious').onclick=function(){
                changeImage(-1);
                return false;
            }

            var images =["slika1.jpg","slika2.jpg", "slika3.jpg" ];
            var caption=["slika1", "slika2", "slika3"];

            var imageNumber=0;
            var imageLength=images.length -1;

            function changeImage(x){
            imageNumber+=x;
            if(imageNumber > imageLength){
                imageNumber = 0;
            }
            if(imageNumber < 0){
                imageNumber = imageLength;
            }
            document.getElementById('slideshow').src=images[imageNumber];

          document.getElementById('caption').innerHTML=caption[imageNumber];
            return false;
            }

            function autoRun(){
                setInterval("changeImage(1)", 3000);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite easy to do.

1) Add a global variable `var timer;`

2) At the start of your `changeImage()` function, add this: `autoRun();`

3) Change your `autoRun()` function to this:

```
function autoRun(){
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout("changeImage(1)", 3000);
}
```

This way the autorun-timer is reset everytime `changeImage()` is invoked, whether that happens because you manually changed the slide or the autorun-function did.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works like a charm!  I just dont understand how does autoRun () function resets changeImage() function only with variable timer;  clearTimeout(timer) when in that moment variable is empty?

Comment: @AljosaBoskovic you are right, the first time `autoRun()` in invoked (on page-load), `clearTimeout(timer);` is technically trying to clear an empty variable, but that doesn't generate an error so that's completely fine. And immediately after that, the `var timer` gets the value of the timeout. And only after that, `changeImage()` will be invoked for the first time, which in turn will invoke `autoRun()` again, where [clearTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) will stop the timeout if it's still running, and after that the timeout is set again to 3 seconds.

Comment: You could do this: `if (timer!=null) {clearTimeout(timer);}`, but it's not necessary.

Comment: Now i understand, at first(on page load) invoked autoRun(); function tries to reset empty variable(which isnt possible), but next moment function changeImage(); is assigned to that variable(timer), then every time when changeImage(); function is invoked (automatically or manually) it resets itself. and then again and again. Nice idea, i couldnt figure it out myself!Thank you very much you helped me a lot, i am currently working on a web site which has this slideshow at the very top of the page, but i noticed this interruption which sometimes look really bad.